# Django Schemas Cross Domain Login

Tags: jquery, django, reactjs, django-rest-framework, cross-domain

I am working with a multi-tenant site using [django-tenant-schemas](https://github.com/bernardopires/django-tenant-schemas) the schemas are using React.

The site of the public schema (the main schema) is used just to create other  schemas that has their own API and their own userbases.
For example:

> example.com
>
> company1.example.com
>
> company2.example.com

Each company schema has its own login page and is using authtoken from django rest framework for the user to remain logged in the site.

Now it is needed to create a public login page, the user can login from the example.com page and be redirected to, for example, company1.example.com and must be logged.

Here is my authentication code to login a user in a tenant (not public) page:

```
module.exports = {
    login: function(username, pass, cb) {
        if (localStorage.token) {
            if (cb) cb(true)
            return
        }
        this.getToken(username, pass, (res) => {
            if (res.authenticated) {
                localStorage.token = res.token
                if (cb) cb(true)
            } else {
                if (cb) cb(false)
            }
        })
    },        

    logout: function() {
        delete localStorage.token
    },

    loggedIn: function() {
        return !!localStorage.token
    },

    getToken: function(username, pass, cb) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/obtain-auth-token/',
            data: {
                email_or_username: username,
                password: pass
            },
            success: function(res){
                cb({
                    authenticated: true,
                    token: res.token
                })
            },
            error: function () { cb({authenticated: false}); }
        })
    }, 
}
```

How can I do something similar to this authentication FROM the public page.

Note: I am using Django Rest Framework to create the user api.